# Combine results from SQL SELECT into string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Say for example we have the following table:

```
Address Line 1 | Address Line 2 | Address Line 3 | Town | Region | Postcode
```

Is there a way of selecting all rows from this and then returning the row as one string e.g

```
AddressLine1 + AddressLine 2 + AddressLine 3 etc.....
```

I apologise if this is a basic question, very new to SQL

Comment: Some form of string concatenation is supported in every RDBMS.  MS SQL Server uses `+`, Oracle uses `||`, MySQL uses `CONCAT()`. What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Are these tables linked to each other via any relation, i mean is there any ForeignKey or PrimaryKey in these tables

Comment: @Michael i am using MS SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MS SQL this is what I would use:

```
SELECT    ([Address Line 1] + ', ' + [Address Line 2] + ', ' + [Address Line 3] + ', ' 
          + Town + ', ' + Region + ', ' + Postcode) AS Address
FROM      TableName
```

Comment: When i save the results as a .CSV from the output window and open in excel, they are still separated by columns? I removed the commas from your query too? Any ideas as to the issue?

Comment: @john I have just tried what you described, in fact I tried without any separators, just spaces and zero length separators, then saved as a .csv from the Results screen and opened in Excel 2007. Unfortunately I can't seem to replicate your issue. The only time I get the data separated into different columns is when I have commas as I do in the example I gave above!

Comment: @john, Just copy the result by right click and paste it to the excel file directly.

Answer (score 2):

In oracle I used ||

```
Select AddressLine1 || ',' || AddressLine2 from address;
```

Syntax will be different in different database servers

Comment: The `||` is the standard concat operator but many DBMS support only proprietary operators, like `+`.

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL you should use the `CONCAT()` function, so:

```
SELECT CONCAT( AddressLine1, ', ', AddressLine2, ', ', AddressLine3, ', ', Town, ', ', Region, ', ', Postcode ) AS LongAddress 
FROM ADDRESSES;
```

But if you want to avoid to add the `', '` between every field, you should use `CONCAT_WS()` instead:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS( ', ', AddressLine1, AddressLine2, AddressLine3, Town, Region, Postcode ) AS LongAddress 
FROM ADDRESSES;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (SQL Server)

Please **donot forget to use ISNULL()** function, which just converts the column to '' if it is a null. If you do not do that , your entire row would be blank if any of the columns is null

```
select isnull([Address Line 1],'')+' '+
       isnull([Address Line 2],'')+' '+
       isnull([Address Line 3],'')+' '+
       isnull(Town,'') +' '+ 
       isnull(Region,'') +' '+ 
       isnull(Postcode,'')
from <table>
```

Comment: @podiluska: no.. I want to add a space after each column... :)

Answer (score 0):

I realized the SQL-Server 2008 tag but just as an FYI, SQL Server 2012 implemented the CONCAT function so you could do something like CONCAT (AddressLine1, ',' , AddressLine2) and so one. And a good thing is that this function treats NULLS as empty strings so "Joe G Joseph" worries won't exist anynore on SQL 2012 :)